# AppleScript Text delimiter

Tags: javascript, applescript, delimiter, csv

I'm getting a report with multiple lines, e.g :

Row 1 20170719-5749-MMFF1FHDKS-23
Row 2 20170717-5749-MMYG8GBTGK-23
Row 3 20170719-5749-ML2Y7HYLJ3-9

and I would like to extract for each, MMFF1FHDKS, MMYG8GBTGK, ML2Y7HYLJ3 and so on, add them in a array and also in the clipboard as text in this format :

MMFF1FHDKS, MMYG8GBTGK, ML2Y7HYLJ3

I know I have to use text delimiter but how can I get this value which are random ?

For information the numbers are not always the same, the number of row is random and the sender can't change the format of the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are always 3 hyphens in each line and the requested string is right before the last hyphen you can use

```
set theRows to "20170719-5749-MMFF1FHDKS-23
20170717-5749-MMYG8GBTGK-23
20170719-5749-ML2Y7HYLJ3-9"

set theResult to {}
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "-"}
repeat with row in (get paragraphs of theRows)
    set end of theResult to text item 3 of row
end repeat
set text item delimiters to ", "
set the clipboard to theResult as text
set text item delimiters to TID
```